# Does xtend support multiple constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, xtend

I'm using eclipse IDE. The first constructor is callable but not the second. I'm wondering if xtend supports multiple constructors?

```
@Data abstract class MatchingBase implements TidilySerializable {
  val List<Integer> connections

  new (int componentSize) {
    connections = (0 ..< componentSize).toList
  }

  new (List<Integer> conn) {
    connections = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    for (int i : 0 ..< componentSize)
      connections.add(conn.get(i))
  }
}

@Data class Permutation extends MatchingBase {
}
```

Then if I call `new Permutation(new ArrayList<Integer>())` in eclipse underlines it as compile time error.

Comment: what is exactly not working for you? and of course. like in java. only one constructor is called unless you call one from another

Comment: Yes, it does. Please provide a [MCVE] and describe what exactly is going wrong, including any error message you get, so we can properly help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it supports multiple constructors. However, I believe the error is occurring because of your second constructor. In the scope of the second constructor it does not know what `componentSize` is. Did you mean something like

```
new (List<Integer> conn) {
    connections = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    for (int i : 0 ..< conn.size) {
        connections.add(conn.get(i))
    }
}
```

Take a look at the docs [here](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/202_xtend_classes_members.html) for more information regarding xtend constructors